# How to do a direct insert into SQL Server 2008 service broker queue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, service-broker

I am researching SQL Server 2008 Service Broker. I want to get data from a web service and insert it into a queue. I understand sending messages from one queue to another, but how do I get the data into the first queue, in the first place?

Comment: I am not sure I am answering your question but I use SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services) to push the data from a MS SharePoint list, through the SPS web service, to a database.

Comment: I think I'm asking the same question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14631474/simply-add-a-message-to-a-sql-server-service-broker-queue-using-t-sql

Answer (score 1):

When you [`SEND`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188407.aspx) a message, its goes directly to transmission queue and from transmission queue to target services queue.

If you want to keep message for the lifetime of conversation, then you can [`ALTER QUEUE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189529.aspx) and use `RETENTION = ON`. In this case, message will be deleted from sender queue, when conversation ends.