# Simply add a message to a SQL Server Service Broker queue using T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, service-broker

I created a queue thus:

```
CREATE QUEUE log_line_queue
WITH RETENTION = ON, --can decrease performance
    STATUS = ON,
    ACTIVATION (
        MAX_QUEUE_READERS = 1, --number of concurrent instances of sp_insert_log_line
        PROCEDURE_NAME = sp_insert_log_line,
        EXECUTE AS OWNER
        );
```

What can I do quickly in SSMS to add an item to my queue using T-SQL?

Comment: You [`SEND`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188407.aspx) a message to the queue (more precisely, using a conversation), but as the examples in the documentation show, you also need a service, message type, contract and conversation first. I suspect you are really asking for a complete example of using a Service Broker queue? If so, there are many online such as [this one](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/09/21/sql-server-intorduction-to-service-broker-and-sample-script/).

Comment: That example, like lots of others I've seen, has a send queue and a receive queue. I just have one queue.

Comment: A conversation is always between two services, but [multiple services can use the same queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171609(v=sql.105).aspx). So both your send and receive services can use the same queue, although please note that the documentation discourages this and recommends only one service per queue; I'm not sure why you don't just create a second queue anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SSMS select required database in Object Explorer. Then find Service Broker of this database, right click on it and select 'New Service Broker Application...' command. This will create template for you to start using Service Broker quickly. Also you'll see minimal recommended configuration needed to implement and run your own application.

As for using one queue - if this is your first experience with Service Broker why not to follow common practice at the beginning? After running several samples and/or your own prototypes you decide how much queues to use and you know how to do it.

Comment: Why would I want to use two queues? I'm using queuing to create a buffer. Several things will write to it and a stored procedure will read from it and insert to database. Can't see how I need two queues, unless they are not really queues in the conventional sense. What am I missing?

Comment: Service Broker's task is to deliver messages from Initiator to Target. Initiator places its message to its queue, Service Broker transfer the message and places to Target's queue. From my point of view if you have several Initiators you need to organize separate queue for each of them. Thus resulting system is more flexible and reliable. You can count all these queues as one buffer - there is no rule '1 buffer = 1 queue'. From the other side, of course, you can use one queue for all these messages exchange, why not - configure it and SB will definitely work. But initially its not good for SB.

Comment: This was finally demystified for me by http://stackoverflow.com/a/14661442/127434